# Sub Total is not getting the changed value from database to input box

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to get the sub total updated, when adding the items to the database from java-script. But, currently it displays the first amount and not updates when adding items. (But when runs the query from phpMyAdmin it works correctly)

[image]

[image]

### java-script code

```
function showSubTotal() {
     <?php $resultT=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM sales_temp");
              $rowT = mysqli_fetch_row($resultT);
              ?>
        document.getElementById("txtSubTotal").setAttribute('value','');
        document.getElementById("txtSubTotal").setAttribute('value',"<?php echo $rowT[0]; ?>");
  }
```

### HTML code

```
<input name="txtSubTotal" type="text" id="txtSubTotal" size="15" / >

<button type="button" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" onclick="submitdata(); check_qty(); showSubTotal();">ADD</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, added the `do_onload(id)` to calculate the total on `loadComplete` event which is triggered after each refresh (also after delete)

```
function do_onload(id)
{
//alert('Simulating, data on load event')

var s = $("#list").jqGrid('getCol', 'amount', false, 'sum');
jQuery("#txtSubTotal").val(s);
}
```

And changed the phpgrid code accordingly.

```
$opt["loadComplete"] = "function(ids) { do_onload(ids); }";
$grid->set_options($opt);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that when you declare the function with PHP, the function cannot be refreshed by using PHP again... because everything that PHP does, happens before the page is loaded, therefore, let's say as an example:

```
function showSubTotal() {
 <?php $resultT=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM sales_temp");
          $rowT = mysqli_fetch_row($resultT);
          ?>
    document.getElementById("txtSubTotal").setAttribute('value','');
    document.getElementById("txtSubTotal").setAttribute('value',"<?php echo $rowT[0]; ?>");
```

}

this 'value' from $rowT[0] = 10 from the first query, it will always be 10, because that is what PHP read from the database when it checked upon page load. You will have to use something like jquery or ajax to read the contents of another php file that contains the value (the mysqli_fetch_row).

PHP is literally named hypertext preprocessor, meaning everything that is processed before the html is printed to the user. (before the page has finished loading)

try experimenting with this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you direct me how to overcome from this as you suggested, since I am not good at jQuery/ajax.

Comment: Certainly, you can rewrite the function showSubTotal(); and you have to make a new file, call it... sum.php and its contents should be:

Comment: <?php $resultT=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM sales_temp");
              $rowT = mysqli_fetch_row($resultT); echo $rowT[0];
              ?>

Comment: showSubTotal() {
$.get( "sum.php", function(data) {
  document.getElementById("txtSubTotal").setAttribute('value',data);
});
}

Comment: now it is important that you download jquery and add it to your within the head of your document together with your other css files or javascript files. http://jquery.com

Comment: I cannot guarentee that the code I provided works, since I haven't tested it, you can use it as reference, and experiment with it, to develop it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`ShowSubTotal()` will bring only the value when the page loads. Dynamic actions will not make any changes, because php needs an server request to operate.

You should bring the subtotal through a dynamic request (ajax) call. 
Or:
Use javascript to sum the values and set the value in your `txtSubTotal` field. If you go for this option, remember to not rely on this value on your server side processing, as it may be adulterated by users.

Comment: @leo-ap Thanks for the explanation. Can you direct me how to overcome from this as you suggested, since I am not good at ajax.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
        url : file_url.php,
        type : 'post',
        data : {                
            get_subtotal:"subtotal",
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            alert(response);
            $("#txtSubTotal").val(response );
        },
        error: function(response) {  
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

file_url.php

```
     if(isset($_POST['get_subtotal'])){
          $resultT=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM sales_temp");
          $rowT = mysqli_fetch_row($resultT);
          echo $rowT[0];
     }
```